# Stop additional click events on specific element ID - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a snippet of my jQuery code;

```
    $('#elements').on('click', '.items', function () {
    var content, id, tag;

    tag = this.tagName;
    id = $('#' + this.id);
    content = id.html();
    switch (tag.substr(0, 1)) {
        case "P":
            id.html("<textarea id='" + this.id + "In' class='" + tag + "In' type='text'>" + content + "</textarea>");
            break;
        case "H":
            id.html("<input id='" + this.id + "In' class='" + tag + "In' value='" + content + "' >");
            break;
    }
});
```

The purpose of this is when I click on a paragraph tag, it will add a text area inside of the paragraph tag (with the content inside it ready for editing). When I click a heading tag, it will create an 'input' tag with the content inside it for editing.

Unfortunately, when i click twice on the paragraph, it adds a text area with the content inside it as it should but on the second click it adds another text area inside of that, now the 'content' of the textarea is: `<textarea id="2In" class="PIn" type="text">Paragraph one.` and with every click it adds: `<textarea id="2In" class="PIn" type="text">`

I understand this is happening as it should given the code but I want to stop the click event on that specific ID (this.id) but keep the click event active on the other elements with the class '.items'.

**Additionally: ** 
I'm sure this is bad practice to approach this by creating the editiable tags inside of the old ones so if anyone has a better approach be sure to let me know.

Many thanks,
Mike

Comment: Side note: You're creating multiple elements with the same `id` (the paragraph, and the `input`/`textarea` inside it). That's not valid. `id` values **must** be unique on a page.

Comment: have you thought of having the `input` below the tag in question and have an accordion type thing to hide/show/enable for the Edit functionality

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably solve it by adding a `:not(.clicked)` to the selector, and adding that class when you add the `input`. E.g.:

```
$('#elements').on('click', '.items:not(.clicked)', function () {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    // ...your current handling...
});
```

---

But you *could* solve it by checking for the existence of the field, provided the `input` or `textarea` you're adding is the only one the paragraph will have:

```
$('#elements').on('click', '.items', function () {
    if (!$(this).find("input, textarea")[0]) {
        // ...your current handling...
    }
});
```

Or actually jQuery extends CSS to provide `:has` and to allow `:not` to have more complex contents, so in theory this would work:

```
$('#elements').on('click', '.items:not(:has(input)):not(:has(textarea))', function () {
    // ...your current handling...
});
```

...but that selector is getting a bit unwieldy...

Comment: or it could be too as selector: `.items:not(:has(textarea))`

Comment: @A.Wolff: True. jQuery's had enough `:has` bugs over the years for me to stay away from it... :-) And it gets a bit long: `.items:not(:has(input)):not(:has(textarea))`. Still, added it as an option.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `.one`?

By using one, the click event can only be triggered once. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/v1432gs4/).

```
$('#elements > *').one('click', function () {
    var content, id, tag;

    tag = this.tagName;
    id = $('#' + this.id);
    content = id.html();
    switch (tag.substr(0, 1)) {
        case "P":
            id.html("<textarea id='" + this.id + "In' class='" + tag + "In' type='text'>" + content + "</textarea>");
            break;
        case "H":
            id.html("<input id='" + this.id + "In' class='" + tag + "In' value='" + content + "' >");
            break;
    }
});
```

But it seems you are trying to do something like allowing a user to edit text and saving the new input. I'd advise using a combination of `contenteditable` and `localStorage`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do. Could you possibly go into more detail?

Comment: I don't have time tonight, but I'll edit my post in the next days. Here are some good links to get you started. On [localStorage](http://codular.com/localstorage), and on [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable). I'd do something as: watch for the `change` event, save the edited text in localStorage. This way, even when a user loses connection or something goes wrong, the edited text is returned. (You can see it as a cookie that is saved.)